# Asking Someone How Their Chinese Studies Are Going

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure

I have a friend who has started learning Mandarin, and I want to ask them how their Mandarin studies are going. The first phrase that comes to mind is this:

你中文学习得怎么样？

I'm not sure, however, if 怎么样 is correct. I don't actually know its exact meaning, but I've always thought of it as "how's it going?", such as in “你过得怎么样？”. Therefore, in this case, "it" would be the person's Chinese studies.

Is this correct? If not, what would be a better way to ask this question?

Comment: If you're using 得 it should be more like, 学习中文学得怎么样？or 学得怎么样？for short

Comment: Understandable and grammatical, but doesn't sound native enough. I wound say "你中文学得怎（么）样了？" Different from "你过得怎么样？", 了 here implies you're asking "the result after a period of learning" but not "the status of the listener's Chinese level (in a long-term sense)".

Comment: big agree with @Stan, in the sentence, add a 了 is sound more like a native  style

Comment: 中文學得怎樣 or 中文學得如何

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. It sounds native enough. 
"怎么样" in this sentence is used for asking how the things are. i.e. Are they good or bad? It's the same in "你过得怎么样" (literally "How are you getting along (these days)? ")
Your friend could answer "还行" ("not so bad") "很好" ("very well") or "不怎么顺利" ("not so well"), as a few examples.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between "你英文学得怎么样?" and "你英文学得怎么样了?" For the first question, I will answer the level of my English, something like "Not bad, I've passed CET6"; however for the latter one, I would consider that's a question for "how's my recent English study going", and then I would answer something like "I've finished all the word lists in the textbook, so I think the exam won't be a problem for me."

Comment: So is "___怎么样" similar to saying "___好不好"?

Comment: No. "怎么样" is closer to "how's it going?" as described in your question. "好不好" seems to be a word asking for (his Chinese) level.

Answer (score 0):

I would just say this: 你最近中文学习怎么样？

Answer (score -1):

你的中文学得怎么样？colloquial
你的中文学得咋样？dialect
你的中文学得如何？style of written language